# How do I pass in a host and port parameter into ant to be used by a Java main function

Tags: java, ant

I am having considerable difficulty finding out how to use args in ant targets properly.

I have an ant target, "our-client," which should take two (or zero) arguments, a host and a port for the client to listen to. I thought that it would be easy to pass in arguments to the shell by typing:

```
ant our-client -Dhost.arg=127.0.0.1 -Dport.arg=8081
```

This does not appear to work. In my program's main function, I have a logger which prints out the host and port that were passed in. I will get to that after I explain what I have in my ant build file.

This is the target that I have written for the client.

```
<target name="our-client" depends="package" description="compiles, packages, and runs the student client">
    <java jar="${java.dist}/catan-client.jar" dir="${java.dist}" fork="yes">
        <arg value="${host.arg}"/>
        <arg value="${port.arg}"/>
        <sysproperty key="com.sun.management.jmxremote" value=""/>
        <assertions>
            <enable/>
        </assertions>
    </java>
</target>
```

The part that I can't seem to understand is how these "arg's" work. Up at the top of the ant build file, I have defined these two properties as follows.

```
<property name="port.arg" value="8081"/>
<property name="host.arg" value="localhost"/>
```

I did this so that parameters were optional for this particular target. If none were supplied, it would run on the default settings.

Getting back to the main function for my program. Regardless of what I type into the command line, the host is always set to localhost, and the port is similarly set to 8081. Here is the logging part inside of my main function

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
...
  if (args.length == 2)
  {
    String host = args[0];
    String port = args[1];
    LOGGER.info("host: " + host + ", port: " + port);
  }
...
}
```

The command line always displays:

```
INFO: host: localhost, port: 8081
```

I think that I must be messing up something in the ant command call. It looks to me that it ignores the input and goes with the default value of each property.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `-Dhost=127.0.0.1 -Dport=8081` sets the properties `host` and `port`, not `host.arg` and `port.arg`. Use `${host}` and `${port}` to refer to the command-line arguments.

Comment: I apologize. I mis-typed my command. I meant to type. `-Dhost.arg=127.0.0.1 -Dport.arg=8081` I will fix my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is from using PowerShell. Although your ant command works in Command Prompt, it won't work as it is in PowerShell.
In PowerShell, if argument names have a period (".") in it, PowerShell will read it as something else (possibly another ant command). Instead, try doing this:

```
ant our-client "-Dhost.arg=127.0.0.1" "-Dport.arg=8081"
```